# Whether or not inclusion of System as an Actor in Use Case Diagram when it is implicitly doing work

Tags: uml, use-case

I need to draw a UML use case diagram for a system.In my system,it generates a loginID and password to those who register.Should I include the system as an actor in it?

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. The system under consideration is never an actor (to self). It is THE system that adds value to its actors.

Answer (score 2):

According to UML specification actor is one of the three:

- A person interacting with the system (for computer systems: a user)
- Other systems interacting with the system (e.g. bank system when our system directly retrieves account history to import payments)
- Hardware interacting with the systems (e.g. sensors or printers).

This list is closed. Neither the system in consideration not any of its parts are actors to the same system.

As a rule of thumb actors are always **external** to the system.